# LXDE: how to make active window in lxpanel distinguishable from inactive one?

Tags: openbox, lxde

In `LXDE`, the task bar shows tabs for all currently running applications/windows, as shown on the screenshot below:

[image]

The problem is, I have hard time distinguishing which window is the one I am in right now (active window)

All tabs look the same to me. Is there any way to configure active window to have another color ?

Comment: I do not have an LXDE setup to try but was wondering if you can control the task bar in a similar fashion as you can control things such as `gnome-terminal` as described here: http://harts.net/reece/2013/02/26/highlighting-the-active-tab-in-gnome-terminal/. This SU Q&A led me to that link: http://superuser.com/questions/698122/change-color-of-active-tab-for-roxterm-on-xfce-lxde

Comment: Which taskbar are you using? gnome-panel? There is a list of taskbars and pagers here https://wiki.debian.org/Openbox#Taskbars_and_pagers

Comment: @RyanLoremIpsum - I am using `lxpanel`. I have pure LXDE without any gnome components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue in `LXDE`. After some investigation, I found out that this setting comes from `gtk` theme.

Go to your gtk theme, ie

`/usr/share/themes/<your_theme_name>/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

And find the "button" section. Add the following `bg[ACTIVE]` line:

```
style "button" {
....
bg[ACTIVE]        = shade (0.55, "#804c44")
...
}
```

adjust the color code `#804c44` as appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

There is no option to change the appearance for the active window in lxpanel's Task Bar (Window List) plugin. You can patch the lxpanel source file launchtaskbar.c in the most recent version, LX Panel 0.7.1. - [LXDE - Lightweight X Desktop Environment -  Browse /LXPanel (desktop panel) at SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lxde/files/LXPanel%20%28desktop%20panel%29/)

For example, you could make the active window use bold font while using the flat button style:

Find line 1589 of launchtaskbar.c which reads:
`gboolean bold_style = (((tk->entered_state) || (tk->flash_state)) && (tk->tb->flat_button));`

Replace with:
`gboolean bold_style = (((tk->entered_state) || (tk->flash_state) || (tk->focused)) && (tk->tb->flat_button));`

The only change is that `tk->focused` was added to `bold_style` to check if the window for that item is focused.

Ultimately, it require some knowledge of coding in C to add custom functionality to the appearance. If you're not familiar with patching, research the topics [HowTo Apply a Patch File To My Linux / UNIX Source Code](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appy-patch-file-using-patch-command/) and [How to Compile and Install Software from Source Code on Linux](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/install-from-source/).

---

The above example is from the following patch which appears to be outdated since it targets the file name taskbar.c instead of launchtaskbar.c. - [LXDE - Lightweight X Desktop Environment / Feature Requests / #213 [lxpanel][taskbar] highlight active task with flat buttons](http://sourceforge.net/p/lxde/feature-requests/213/)

**Update:** I compiled a patched source with the above code on lxpanel-0.6.1 and it was glitchy. It kept reloading lxpanel. You might try an SE network that's more oriented toward coding to figure out how to customize it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You could try playing with the options available when you right click on the panel and select *Panel Settings* from the context menu. When the *Panel Preferences* window opens, click on the *Panel Applets* tab. Find and click on the *Task Bar (Window List)* line. Then click on the *Edit* button on the right side of the window.

[image: ss#1]

#### References

- [LXDE: Tips & Tricks](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201011/page11.html)

Comment: thanks for the tip, but unfortunately there does not seem to be any settings relevant to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For Fedora 30 through 32, I couldn't find a place to add the `style "button"` code in Thomas Keller's answer, so I went poking around.

Note that the desktop theme is different from what Openbox is using.  Openbox was set to "Onyx" by default, but the desktop theme is "Adwaita":

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
'Adwaita'
```

In the directory `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0` you will find that `gtkrc` loads `main.rc` which contains the following:

```
    ###########
    # Buttons #
    ###########

    image {
      function = BOX
      state    = NORMAL
      file     = "assets/button.png"
      border   = {4, 4, 4, 4}
      stretch  = TRUE
    }

...

    image {
      function = BOX
      state    = ACTIVE
      file     = "assets/button-active.png"
      border   = {4, 4, 4, 4}
      stretch  = TRUE
    }
```

As shown, these files are in the `assets` subdirectory.  Here they are, side-by-side to show the difference.  It's there, but very hard to see in the task bar.  On the left is the default button, on the right the button for the active window.  These are stretched to fit the space available.

[image][image]

I opened the file in a PNG editor and added a dark outline.  Now it's obvious which window is active.  Darkening the shade of the button in the editor would be just as easy.

[image]

Sorry for the lack of a screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20160826032523/http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXPanel_Theming) may help to edit the current used gtk theme under `/usr/share/themes/USED-THEME/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

Here is an example with qtcurve theme (PNGs token from Breeze-Dark theme):

```
style "qtcurve-h2" = "qtcurve-default"
{
  xthickness = 1
  ythickness = 2

  engine "pixmap" {
    image {
      function = BOX
      state    = NORMAL
      file     = "../assets/button.png"
      border   = {4, 4, 4, 4}
      stretch  = TRUE
    }
    image {
      function = BOX
      state    = ACTIVE
      file     = "../assets/button-active.png"
      border   = {4, 4, 4, 4}
      stretch  = TRUE
    }
    image {
      function = BOX
      state    = PRELIGHT
      file     = "../assets/button-hover.png"
      border   = { 1, 1, 1, 1 }
      stretch  = TRUE
    }
  }
}

class "*Button" style "qtcurve-h2"
```