# Fbpanel on multiple monitors: how to filter displayed application per screen?

Tags: x11, multi-monitor, openbox, fbpanel

Based on my earlier [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559417/fbpanel-only-use-one-monitor) and answer from [Arkadiusz Drabczyk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559417/fbpanel-only-use-one-monitor/560199#560199), I have set up 3 different instances of fbpanel, separate one for each of my 3 monitors:

This is how I start fbpanel:

```
fbpanel -x 0 --profile left &
fbpanel -x 1 --profile center &
fbpanel -x 2 --profile right &
```

The 3 profiles `left`, `center` and `right` are defined in my `~/.config/fbpanel/`. The  profile `center` contains definition of the `taskbar` plugin, ie the active windows currently open are visible on the tab, and can be switched between (alt+tab) or "minimised"

```
Plugin {
type = taskbar
expand = true
config {
    ShowIconified = true
    ShowMapped = true
    ShowAllDesks = false
    tooltips = true
    IconsOnly = false
    MaxTaskWidth = 150
}
```

But the `taskbar` on the center monitor contains all applications (from all 3 monitors). So I have one `taskbar` for 3 monitors.

I would like to have one `taskbar` for each of my 3 `fbpanels`, where only applications currently occupying left monitor would be on the left fbpanel's taskbar, and so on

So basically, if I move application window form center monitor to left monitor, the application currently "docked" on the center fbpanel's taskbar should move to left fbpanel's taskbar.

I have no idea if this is possible.

More details to my setup:

Im using `fbpanel` in `openbox`, my OS is Debian Buster. I would be happy to recompile the `fbpanel` package, if that would solve my problem.

Comment: Since you mention openbox, I noticed [tint2](https://gitlab.com/o9000/tint2) claims to have: *Multi-monitor capability: create one panel per monitor, showing only the tasks from the current monitor;* (I haven't tried it).

Comment: The functionality is not there and you have to patch the current source to have it (as intika pointed out).  It also isn't completely clear how you would like `taskbar` to work.  You would like the taskbar to be activated only on the screen where the mouse cursor is (the others would be inactive)?  Or would you like to show taskbar where you have active window? Or would you like to have one task bar which would show application on each screen somehow differenciated like background color?  I wanted to point out that this issue is not completely streightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Fbpanel

The [Fbpanel](https://github.com/aanatoly/fbpanel)'s plugin [taskbar](https://github.com/aanatoly/fbpanel/tree/master/plugins/taskbar) does not implement such feature (this is confirmed after reviewing the [plugin's sources](https://github.com/aanatoly/fbpanel/blob/master/plugins/taskbar/taskbar.c)).

The only available option are defined as follow:

```
XCG(xc, "tooltips", &tb->tooltips, enum, bool_enum);
XCG(xc, "iconsonly", &tb->icons_only, enum, bool_enum);
XCG(xc, "acceptskippager", &tb->accept_skip_pager, enum, bool_enum);
XCG(xc, "showiconified", &tb->show_iconified, enum, bool_enum);
XCG(xc, "showalldesks", &tb->show_all_desks, enum, bool_enum);
XCG(xc, "showmapped", &tb->show_mapped, enum, bool_enum);
XCG(xc, "usemousewheel", &tb->use_mouse_wheel, enum, bool_enum);
XCG(xc, "useurgencyhint", &tb->use_urgency_hint, enum, bool_enum);
XCG(xc, "maxtaskwidth", &tb->task_width_max, int);
```

The available options are not well documented but here are some descriptions:

```
ShowIconified = true # Displays icons on the windows.
ShowMapped = true # If false here, only windows that are minimized are shown.
ShowAllDesks = false # Show the windows of all virtual desktops.
tooltips = true # Displays the complete title of the window when hovering it.
IconsOnly = false # Displays only the icons of the windows and nothing else.
MaxTaskWidth = 150 # Specifies the maximum width of a window in the taskbar.
```

**Without patching the source the only possibility is to use different virtual desktop on your different screens (assign a virtual desktop to each of your screen) then set the option `showalldesks` to false for each of your 3 fbpanels**, such solution (virtual desktop per screen) is discussed in details [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=152442) and [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=155824).

Note also that other [issues](https://github.com/aanatoly/fbpanel/issues/52)/[request](https://sourceforge.net/p/fbpanel/feature-requests/46/) are made upstream without a result.

## Alternatives:

As a side note, reading your other questions about LXDE [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149540/lxde-active-window-in-lxpanel-task-bar-window-list-plugin-is-indistinguishabl) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175204/notify-send-notification-daemon-disable-tray-icon) i guess that you quit using LXDE for those reasons but those past questions seems to have solutions.

Most lightweight desktop's panel like XFCE/LXDE support the needed feature (only display windows's tasks for the current screen) and can be used alone without their full native environment; along with your current Openbox setup (the same way you use Fbpanel).

Here is a non exhaustive list of panels than can be used independently:

**[XFCE panel](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/preferences)**:

```
## install the panel and its dependency
apt-get install xfce4-panel

## start the panel alone
xfce4-panel
```

**[LXDE panel](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXPanel)**:

```
## install the panel and its dependency
apt-get install lxpanel

## start the panel alone
lxpanel
```

**[LXQT panel](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html)**:

```
## install the panel and its dependency
apt-get install lxqt-panel

## start the panel alone
lxqt-panel
```